# iOS 7 How to use NSUserDefaults to save an NSNumber?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I have been trying to use NSUserDefaults to save what level the player is on in my game.

I have been looking on the internet and it seems that you save an object in the app delegate file in the '-(void)didEnterBackground:(UIApplication)application' it gives you whenever you start a new project.

Then you can load the saved object in the '-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions' it gives you. (Sorry I don't know the terminology I am new to programming).

If I type:

```
     //In appDelegate.m, to save the data 

     -(void)didEnterBackground:(UIApplication)application
     {
     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [defaults setObject:levelCounter forKey:@"levelCounterKey";
     [defaults synchronize];
     }

     //also in appDelegate.m, to load the data
     - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:                (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
     {
     NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     NSNumber *levelCounter = [defaults objectForKey:@"levelCounterKey";
```

Apparently this should work but it when I do it , it doesn't seem to save the value of the level, the levelCounter variable is 0 whenever I run the application again, despite the fact that when I stopped running the application it was 1 or 2.

I am using sprite kit and currently running this in the simulator, if that helps.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Did you copy and paste your code? There are several "]" missing

Comment: `levelCounter` is not defined + it is saved only when the app is set in background. Not when the app is killed. Otherwise your code regarding `NSUserDefault` seems ok

Comment: Check this link : http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/07/nsuserdefault-usage.html

Answer (score 3):

Don't save the level in `didEnterBackground:`. It might not get called. If your app is terminated or if it crashes and the user would lose his progress. Save it immediately after he completes a level or loads a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
– floatForKey:  
– integerForKey:  
– doubleForKey:
```

and the corresponding setters.

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is looks like it should work.  If you look in your simulator directory for your application, under `Library/Preferences` you can find the plist file that NSUserDefaults writes into - there you can see what was actually written when the application was suspended.